# LINQ : Generics with IQueryable

Tags: .net, linq, generics

I have to add some "lookup" queries to my C#.NET application. Basically, there will be many tables where they all have the same schema, but contain different values.

I am faced with writing the same code over and over (should be an OO way to do this..)

[edit - below is modified to show more complete info]
Anyways, what I would like to do is:

```
public List<GenericLookupE>         GetLookupItems( string what )
{
    // create db thing
    if ( "regions" == what )  return FetchLookup( db.lkRegions.AsQueryable() );
    if ( "partners" == what ) return FetchLookup( db.lkPartners.AsQueryable() );
    if ( "funders" == what )  return FetchLookup( db.lkFunders.AsQueryable() );

    return null; // or something more intelligent than that =)
}


private List<GenericLookupE>        FetchLookup<T>( IQueryable<T> lookup )
{
    return lookup.OrderBy( p => p.Sequence ).Select
    (   p => new GenericLookupE()
        {
            ID      = p.ID
            ,Label      = p.Label
            ,StateCode  = p.StateCode
            ,Sequence   = p.Sequence
        }
    ).ToList();
}
```

of course, the problem is the compiler doesn't know what 'p => p.Sequence' is.
Any ideas?

Thank you all.

Comment: No one here knows what `p => p.Sequence` is either ... can you elaborate on that?

Comment: i was just coming to the same conclusion. -- updated the question

Answer (score 3):

Type constraints on generics are your friend. With a base type or interface containing Sequence:

```
where T : IMyBaseInterface
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Add a common interface to your `Т` classes, define `Sequence` there, and add a constraint to your generic requiring `Т` parameters to implement the common interface.

```
interface ICommonInterface { // This is an awful name, please pick something better
    int Sequence { get }
}

private List<GenericLookupE> FetchLookup<T>( IQueryable<T> lookup ) where T : ICommonInterface {
    // Your stuff here
}
```

Comment: sitbacken watch: hmm.. i understand your idea, but the problem isn't that the compiler doesn't understand GenericLookupE, but the fields in the table (p.Sequence and the others), and chokes on *that*. (or maybe i don't understand your idea.. =)

Comment: @horace sorry, I typed `GenericLookupE` instead of `T`.

Answer (score 1):

The clean solution is to use a common base type or common interface.

If for some reason this is not possible, here's a way to construct the expression you want dynamically:

```
// Returns an expression of the form: p => new GenericLookupE
// { ID = p.ID, Label = p.Label, StateCode = p.StateCode, Sequence = p.Sequence }
// Can be written as a more generic 'auto-mapper', but
// this sample only solves your specific problem.
static Expression<Func<T, GenericLookupE>> GetLookupMapper<T>()
{ 
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

    string[] properties = { "ID", "Label", "StateCode", "Sequence" };

    var bindings = from propName in properties
                   let source = Expression.Property(parameter, propName)
                   let target = typeof(GenericLookupE).GetProperty(propName)
                   select Expression.Bind(target, source);    

    var newExp = Expression.New(typeof(GenericLookupE));    
    var body = Expression.MemberInit(newExp, bindings);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, GenericLookupE>>(body, parameter);
}
```

And then your method becomes:

```
private List<GenericLookupE> FetchLookup<T>(IQueryable<T> lookup)
{
    return lookup.Select(GetLookupMapper<T>())
                 .OrderBy(p => p.Sequence)
                 .ToList();
}
```

I really doubt you need something like this though.

Comment: actually, this looks like the only solution that doesn't require repeating the same code over and over. even if i use the partial class solution, i am looking at writing nearly the same partial class over and over again for each table i want to query from. ... at least your solution eliminates the need to write nearly duplicate code over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Your objects `Regions`, `Partners`, and `Funders` appear to have the same set of properties (`ID`, `Label`, `StateCode`, and `Sequence`).  This is commonly known as "duck typing".

However, to write a "generic" strongly-typed solution that works with all of them, they all have to derive from a common interface or base type that lists these properties!

I see the following 3 solutions:

1. Make `Regions`, `Partners`, and `Funders` inherit a base type (such as `GenericLookupE`), or make them implement a common interface (such as `IGenericLookupE`).

   - If these classes are generated for you, then it might be difficult to do this
   - If you CAN do this, then you can just `.Cast` to the correct type without `Select`ing new objects (**See update**)
2. Use the `dynamic` type or reflection to get the properties (which is loosely-typed, but can work)
3. Create 1-off solutions for each type (which is basically you're trying to avoid)

### Update

Here's some ways to make your database objects implement a common interface, depending on your framework:

[Adding a Base Class (or Interface) to All LINQ to SQL Entities](http://www.davidturvey.com/blog/index.php/2009/11/adding-a-base-class-or-interface-to-all-linq-to-sql-entities/)

[Implementing an interface on a LINQ to SQL object using a partial class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609215/can-you-implement-an-interface-on-a-linq2sql-class)

Comment: hi scott. these objects are database table objects created automagically by dragging the table from the server explorer. do i have control over what they inherit from?

Comment: @horace Assuming you're using LINQ to SQL, I updated my answer with a few links.

Comment: hi scott: well, it really looks like solution 3 (1-off) is just as practical as any. if i have to write a partial class for every type, then i'm actually writing *more* code than just repeating the same code over and over. if i add a property or change the type of a property, i'm faced with a bit more work with the "oo" way than just copy/paste.

Comment: @horace Yeah I agree, it's probably not worth it.  What about adding a base class to all entities?  Did that seem like ti would work?