# Use generic method to return list<T> where T could be one of three types that share the same structure

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have some sql views where different source tables are used, but each view returns exactly the same structure.

So very simplistically:

```
view1
    select tblA.Name as custName,
           tblA.DOB as DateOfBirth,
           tblA.accountBalance as AccountBalance
    from myFirstTable tblA

view2
    select tblB.AccountName as custName,
           tblB.BirthDate as DateOfBirth,
           tblB.Balance as AccountBalance
    from mySecondTable tblB

view3
    select tblC.CustomerName as custName,
           tblC.DateOfBirth as DateOfBirth,
           tblC.accBal as AccountBalance
    from myThirdTable tblC
```

So even though the fieldnames in the source tables are different, the different views return identically-named (and typed) fields. The actual views are complex and massive, running to hundreds of lines each.

I then drag these views into my Linq-to-sql designer and try and use them in a generic class.

```
    public static List<T> MainSearch<T>(ReportParams RP)
    {
        MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RP.appType)) { return null; }

        var searchQuery = new List<T>();

        switch (RP.appType)
        {
            case "type1":
                searchQuery = (from t in dc.view1s select t);
                break;
            case "type2":
                searchQuery = (from t in dc.view2s select t);
                break;
            case "type3":
                searchQuery = (from t in dc.view3s select t);
                break;
        }

        //do other stuff with search query depending on params
        DateTime dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(RP.fromDate);
        searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(q => convert.ToDateTime(q.DateOfBirth) >= dtFrom);

        //and so on...
```

The idea being that a generic front end can be used that passes in parameters depending on user selection and then these parameters are used to narrow down the search results for the specific source data being searched for (it will never be a combination returned, it's always one or other of the three views).

The code above does not work. In my switch statement, the intellisense complains that it cannot implicitly convert from a specific type (of view1, for example) to a generic list of T.  This then stops me using the strong types in lambda expressions further down.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do or am I barking up completely the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't fully tested this but I think you could do it by creating an interface with properties custName, DOB and AccountBalance. Then have each of your generated LINQ-to-SQL classes (tblA, tblB, tblC) implement this interface in a separate partial class file. This should be okay as long as the property names and types match.

```
interface IAccountTable
{
    string custName { get; set; }
    DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    Decimal AccountBalance { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
partial class tblA : IAccountTable
{
}
```

Make your searchQuery a list of that interface.

```
var searchQuery = new List<IAccountTable>();
```

The cast the results of your actual queries to the interface.

```
searchQuery = tblA.Where(t => t.custName == "Uday").Select(t => (IAccountTable)t).ToList();
```

Comment: Linq-to-SQL doesn't support this kind of inheritance though, does it?  Every time I touch the designer I'm going to overwrite any custom changes I make. As the views return approx 60 fields, maintaining it all separately would be kind of depressing but I'm beginning to think I'm going to have to do something like that no matter which approach I take.

Comment: No you don't touch the designer. LINQ-to-SQL creates partial classes. So you can create complementary partial classes in another folder. These are useful for implementing interfaces (as above) or adding custom properties and methods.

Comment: OK... but the partial class in the "...designer.cs" file has to be mapped to the view source on the database so the query knows where to get it from. So I have: ` [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.view1")]` and under that `public partial class view1` and then the list of properties (in the designer.cs file).  Are you saying that I need to change that to just inherit the interface and leave the mapping in there?

Comment: No. Create a separate partial class file for each view with the same class name. Save these in a separate folder and call them tblA.Partial.cs (or whatever). In these new partial class files, specify that the class implements the interface. The compiler will know to combine the separate partial files to a single class.

Comment: Maybe this question and answer makes it clearer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609215/can-you-implement-an-interface-on-a-linq2sql-class

Comment: I've tried dragging in another instance of the view from the server explorer. Then I deleted all the properties and modified the designer to inherit the interface. All seemed fine but as soon as I open and then save the dbml file it wipes out the inheritance.  I don't see how I can have the link to the sql view source without using the dbml?  I can't just create a separate class as the datacontext won't know where to go and get the data from, surely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103288/discussion-between-andyb-and-themook).

Comment: After experimentation, I can say that this is the way to go - thanks for that.  Crucial thing to remember folks, is make sure your linq-to-sql dbml class and your interface and partial class are all in the same namespace!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class that has the same set of properties as returned by the views, then may be you can try something like this:

```
case "type1":
searchquery = (from t in dc.view1s select new commonClass() { CustName = t.CustName, DateOfBirth = t.DateOfBirth, AccountBalance = t.AccountBalance });
                break;
```

and so on for other cases...

Comment: That's nice and simple :)

Comment: It is and it may be the only way forward. It just means that, as each view has about 60 fields, I'm going to end up with 3 lots of 60 manual mappings from the three different views to the common class.  I can copy/paste it and just change the view name, but that seems horribly unelegant!

Comment: I haven't used AutoMapper before, but it may be something worthwhile looking into to get away from using manual mappings. Getting started: [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) Here is an SO question about using AutoMapper to map lists of objects: [Map lists of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276664/automapper-does-it-map-lists-of-objects)

Answer (score -1):

In Entity Framework, the right approach would be to create a separate `TBase`class, that `T1`, `T2`, `T3` would derive from. It would contain all the common properties you need, and therefore there would be no need for the `switch` statement: you would just have `TBase someObj;` and then be able to use `someObj.ACommonProperty` directly.

Comment: I don't think LINQ-to-SQL supports inheritance.

Comment: That's not much help when I'm not using Entity framework though!  I said I was using Linq to SQL.