# How to join table by string name using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am updating some code which contains text-based queries into LINQ-based queries.

In this example,

```cs
var strDeviceType = "Blade";
// code edited for brevity
var strQuery = String.Format(
    " SELECT Test.ID, {0}.Name AS Device " +
    " FROM Test " +
    " INNER JOIN {0} ON DeviceID = {0}.ID ", strDeviceType);
```

I have run into a problem, which is that the table being joined is specified by a string in C#. The possible values of `strDeviceType` are "Blade", "Engine", "Diode" (and more), and these tables are all included in my LINQ-to-SQL model.

This is a query joining the Blade table specifically

```cs
using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
{
    var result = from test in dc.Tests
                 join blade in dc.Blades on test.DeviceID equals blade.ID
                 select new { test.ID, blade.Name };
}
```

How would I replace `... in dc.Blades ...` with the proper collection? i.e. how do I get from the string "Blade" to the collection called `Blades` in the model?

Here is the definition of `Blade` and `Blades` in the auto-generated model (vb.net)

```vb
<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name:="dbo.Blade")>  _
Partial Public Class Blade
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging, 
    System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
' ...
```

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property Blades() As System.Data.Linq.Table(Of Blade)
    Get
        Return Me.GetTable(Of Blade)
    End Get
End Property
```

The other tables are defined similarly. They also have the fields ID, Name - but there is no base class or Interface which they all share which guarantees these properties.

**Edit**

I should have included originally that my intent is to make this query accommodate future additions of tables with ID, Name, which would be used in a similar way, without recompiling the project it is in. The project with the linq-to-sql model can be recompiled easily when tables are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to extend the linq-to-sql classes to implement a common interface, and use that interface in the linq query in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1609237/832052). This works because the linq-to-sql classes are marked `partial`. When adding more tables, only the data context project will need to be recompiled, which is required anyway by the designer. I used reflection to find the `Table<TEntity>` property in the linq-to-sql model by plural name.

I added a vb file alongside the linq-to-sql model with the following code:

```vb
Public Interface IDeviceTable
    Property ID() As Long
    Property Name() As String
End Interface

Partial Public Class Blade
    Implements IDeviceTable
    Public Property ID1 As Long Implements IDeviceTable.ID
        Get
            Return Me.ID
        End Get
        Set(value As Long)
            Me.ID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Name1 As String Implements IDeviceTable.Name
        Get
            Return Me.Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Partial Public Class Diode
    Implements IDeviceTable
    ' etc.
End Class
```

and changed the query:

```cs
using (TeradiodeDataContext dc = new TeradiodeDataContext())
{
    var strDeviceType = "Blade";
    var pluralDeviceType = System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.
                           PluralizationService.CreateService(Application.CurrentCulture).
                           Pluralize(strDeviceType);
    var devices = (System.Data.Linq.Table<IDeviceTable>)dc.GetType().
                   GetProperty(pluralDeviceType).GetValue(dc);

    var result = from test in dc.Tests
                 join blade in devices on test.DeviceID equals blade.ID
                 select new { test.ID, blade.Name };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NO, you can't do it like the way you are doing with string query cause in that case you loose static type safety. You can include a `if..else` condition and based on that evaluation change the collection to join like

```
if(strDeviceType == "Blade")
{
  using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
{
    var result = from test in dc.Tests
                 join blade in dc.Blades on test.DeviceID equals blade.ID
                 select new { test.ID, blade.Name };
}
}
else
{
  using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
{
    var result = from test in dc.Tests
                 join engine in dc.Engine on test.DeviceID equals engine.ID
                 select new { test.ID, engine.Name };
}
}
```

Comment: I've ruled this approach out, because the source of the string could in the future include an additional table name. In which case I would need to recompile to add another case like your example. I am trying to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Device
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int Name { get; set; }

    // if it must be a string, you can use this.
    // public string Type{ get; set; }

    //I personally prefer this approach
    public DeviceType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum DeviceType
{
    Blade = 1, 
    Engine = 2,
    Diode = 3,
}
```

Comment: How would I use this?

Comment: @Verdolino delete the `Blade`, `Engine`, and `Diode` tables and use this instead

Comment: I see... but those classes are auto-generated linq-to-sql classes so they are very much tied into the data context. I'd rather not mess with them. i.e. `Blade.ID` has this attribute: `<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage:="_ID", AutoSync:=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType:="BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey:=true, IsDbGenerated:=true)>` , among all the other SQL specific code

Comment: @Verdolino Is your project already in production? or are you still developing it?

Comment: It's in production, I'm in continuous improvement

Comment: @Verdolino  In that case, you might as well recompile when you add new tables.  If you want __users__ to be able to define new "types" then your best option probably involves  changing your db model in some form or another.

Comment: I understand. I don't mind recompiling the data context (I would need to when I add a table to the graphical model anyway). But it is separate from the part of the code with the query. I think I would stick with the string query over the cascading IF, since it's a lot more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Test.ID is unique across Blade, Engine and Diode, what you could do inside the query is check of existence on each table and then concatenate if there was a match:

```
using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
{
    var result = 
        (from test in dc.Tests
        let blade = (from t in dc.Blade where t.id == test.DeviceID)
        let engine = (from t in dc.Engine where t.id == test.DeviceID)
        let diode = (from t in dc.Diode where t.id == test.DeviceID)
        select new {
            test.ID,
            Device = 
                    (blade.Count() > 0 ? blade.FirstOrDefault().Name : "")  + 
                    (engine.Count() > 0 ? engine.FirstOrDefault().Name : "") + 
                    (diode.Count() > 0 ? diode.FirstOrDefault().Name : "")
        }
        );


}
```